# Wifi can't connect, cable connection barely works

Tags: wireless, networking, 13.04, internet

I'm having problems with the internet connection on my Ubuntu 13.04. I deleted Windows 7 from my computer (where the internet worked without any kind of problems) and installed Ubuntu 13.04, but now i'm having some trouble here.

I can't connect to the internet using my WiFi, it connects to my router. DEPENDING, on the site that I pings on terminal it doesn't have answer. I can't browse on internet using it and Ubuntu can't connect to archive.ubuntu to download packages or updates.

To used my cable connection I had to restart my notebook some times until it connects and it keeps barely working. It seems like I'm using a 90's internet connection. When I try to download or update certain packages, most of the connections to the server are unsuccessful.

I'd like some help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

(Based on input from your other question that got deleted...)

The one thing I can think of that the software center, apt-get, and the "certain websites" you mentioned (including Facebook and YouTube when you're logged in) all have in common is that they use an encrypted connection.

So maybe it's a problem with encrypted connections. Please confirm this by trying out several websites with and without SSL (provided they support it). For example, try both:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page and
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page

If my guess is correct, the first one should load without problems but the second one should be slow.

Now to be honest, I have little clue as to what you should attempt to do in order to fix this. I can suggest one thing that might and might not be useful, and that would be reconfiguring all SSL related packages on your system.

First, query them using:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep ssl
```

Then, after stripping the version and architecture (if any), you can reconfigure them using:

```
dpkg-reconfigure pkg1 pkg2 pkg3 pkg4 etc.
```

You might want to reboot after reconfiguring them.

Also, while at it, you can try booting up a live CD/USB and seeing whether things work well from there.