# Internet doesn't work decently, I'm hardly regretting for chosing Ubuntu

Tags: internet, connection

The internet connects but it doesn't works decently, i can't download or update things using the terminal or the ubuntu program central because the server doesn't answers or because it asks for constant authentication and then doesn't downloads it.

At Firefox (I can't even download Chrome) websites don't load well, but when I download certain things, like a Windows 7 ISO the internet speed is completely normal. I guess it can be some kind of blocking, i don't know.

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: Related to http://askubuntu.com/questions/323664/wifi-cant-connect-cable-connection-barely-works by same poster?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds really odd.  The only thing I could think of is:

1. Checking if it is a server issue relating to the website's server itself.  But it sounds like wit's widespread so this may not be the case.
2. Reinstall your internet drivers.  That may fix the issue although only do this if you know how to.
3. From a quick glance it looks like the servers are having issues. Just check around to see if thats the issue.
4. Check your own internet connection.  There may be some issues that are extending from your own internet connection.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How can I reinstall the internet drivers? I think there's having problems with the connection to every kind of server. It isn't my own internet connection because other machines with Windows work perfectly well in that network.